# Where is Enable 3d manipulator option in user preferences?

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-cursor

I didn't find the *Enable 3D Manipulator* option in *User Preferences > 3D View > 3D View Global* in Blender.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Check *User Preferences > Interface tab > Manipulation: option and dropdown*.

[image]

Note that you can also disable/enable it in the footer of the *3D Viewport*.

*On:*

[image]

*Off:*

[image]

Lastly, as [metaphor_set](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/23985/metaphor-set) points out, you can key <kbd>Space</kbd> to open the *Search* menu and search for *Enable 3D Manipulator*.

Answer (score 2):

The button for enabling the manipulator is at the bottom of the 3D view. But the bottom panel might be hidden. Then you have to press the plus sign to show that panel:

[image: Manipulator Button]

Note: The manipulator only shows the axes for which the Transform Lock is disabled in object mode. Also, the manipulator is not shown if nothing is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Not all options are in the menu. Hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to open the command search and type "manipulator".

[image]

Comment: Thank you but even I click enable 3d manipulator does not show any options does not show enable 3d manipulator window please help and thanks

Comment: Perhaps you want to add a screenshot and highlight what you mean exactly by "does not show enable 3d manipulator window"? It's really hard to under stand...

Comment: Shortuct for enabling 3d manipulator is `Ctrl`+`Space`.

Comment: neither ctrl-space nor searching for "enable 3d" do anything for me in blender 2.8

Answer (score 1):

Right top corner in 3d view[image: Enable Show Gizmo], this will turn on arrows (manipulators)

Comment: While correct it should be mentioned that this is the case for 2.8, the rest of answers are for 2.79 and prior